# Tensorflow.python Framework FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable from container: localhost

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, carla

I am working on a project to simulate the autonomous car driving using CARLA simulator. I read somewhere that keras doesn't handle threading well, is it true?

Also, while running the training script using Tensorflow, we created multiple threads for reinforcement learning. However, we are getting the following error. What could be the reason?

(P.S. I have already tried the session variable tweak for providing more memory.)

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ankit\Anaconda\envs\navigate\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ankit\Anaconda\envs\navigate\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\SDC\Carla-RL-master\sources\trainer.py", line 223, in train_in_loop
    if not self.train():
  File "D:\SDC\Carla-RL-master\sources\trainer.py", line 110, in train
    current_qs_list = self.model.predict(current_states, settings.PREDICTION_BATCH_SIZE)
  File "C:\Users\Ankit\Anaconda\envs\navigate\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1462, in predict
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\Ankit\Anaconda\envs\navigate\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 324, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\Ankit\Anaconda\envs\navigate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3076, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Ankit\Anaconda\envs\navigate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Ankit\Anaconda\envs\navigate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable conv2d_3/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv2d_3/kernel)
         [[{{node conv2d_3/convolution/ReadVariableOp}}]]
         [[{{node dense_2/BiasAdd}}]]
```